# Mousemove event wrong target javascript

Tags: javascript

In what cases can `mousemove` give incorrect target?
I have two elements and `event.target` shows me one div, when in fact the mouse is on another.

Here is the code.

```js
var o = document.getElementById('container');
var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
var ox = 100;
var oy = 100;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    event.returnValue = false;
    var size = {x: o.offsetWidth, y: o.offsetHeight};
    var curX = event.pageX;
    var curY = event.pageY;
    var previousInside = event.target === inner;

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY;
        var dx = x - curX;
        var dy = y - curY;

        var p1 = {x: ox, y: oy};
        var p2 = {x: ox + 50, y: oy + 50};
        p1.x += dx;
        p2.x += dx;
        p1.y += dy;
        p2.y += dy;
        var currentInside = event.target === inner;
        console.log('Was '+ (previousInside? 'inside': 'outside'), 'Now ' + (currentInside?'inside': 'outside'))
        if (p1.x < 40 || p2.x > size.x - 40 || p1.y < 40 || p2.y > size.y - 40) {
            if (currentInside) {
                curX = x;
                curY = y;

            }
            previousInside = currentInside;
            return;

        } else {
            if (currentInside && !previousInside) {
                curX = x;
                curY = y;
                previousInside = currentInside;
                return;
            }

        }
        previousInside = currentInside;
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
        ox = p1.x;
        oy = p1.y;
        inner.style.top = oy +'px';
        inner.style.left = ox+'px';
        return false
    }

    o.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    o.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        o.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    });
}
o.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
```

```html
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 50%; height: 250px; background-color: yellow;">
  <div id="inner" style="position:absolute; width: 50px; height:50px; background-color: red; top:100px; left: 100px">
  </div>
</div>
```

To see a weird behavior, mousedown on the red square and drag it until it stops moving. Drag a bit higher so you are far enough from the red square. Now drag to the right far away from the square. Now drag down and when mouseX will equal red box x, the console will show that Was outside and Now insinde, when in fact it should be Was outside and now inside.

Thank you.

Comment: That's absolutely not true. `Event.target` will **always** show you the exact element. Whereas `Event.currentTarget` (in 99% of cases the preferred property to use BTW) will give you the element which has the listener bound to. PS, you can also use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint - if that applies to your specific case.

Comment: Do you have any example to prove your case? Please never too late to read: [ask] , and [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've added an example.